# How to reflect changes in mayan edms?

Tags: django, python-3.9, mayanedms

I have restart the server using "make runserver" after customizing Mayan Edms. But I dont see the changes. I am using the developer installation. [Development installation link](https://docs.mayan-edms.com/chapters/development/development_deployment.html)

Here is the repo - [Link to Mayan-Edms](https://gitlab.com/mayan-edms/mayan-edms)

Mayan is using Python Django framework.